# Multiple upload in Uploadify with rename - how to send scriptData?

Tags: php, jquery, uploadify, scriptdata

At first, sorry for my bad english.

I am using Uploadify with image cropper to upload and choose your own thumb, but I need to do a multi upload, not single. Now I´m trying to send before each upload - onSelect scriptData to server, but it send only one name, or rewriting it somewhere:( I tried change name of parameter, reset scriptData but with no effect. Problem is, that name of file must generate Javascript, which will send it to server (second option is do it by ajax), because Javascript then show the thumb.

**EDIT** Link is not working, if you want last version, contact jaroslav.streit@gmail.com

*Test is running here http://nabytek-santy.cz/test/*

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Strict//EN">
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Test uploadcropperu</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
        <meta name="author" content="HS Computers - www.hscomputers.cz">
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="uploadcropper/uploadcropper.css">
        <link href='uploadcropper/uploadify/uploadify.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <script type='text/javascript' src='uploadcropper/uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js'>

        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='uploadcropper/uploadify/swfobject.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='uploadcropper/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            <!--
            sdiak = "áäčďéěíĺľňóô öŕšťúů üýřžÁÄČĎÉĚÍĹĽŇÓÔ ÖŔŠŤÚŮ ÜÝŘŽ";
            bdiak = "aacdeeillnoo orstuu uyrzAACDEEILLNOO ORSTUU UYRZ";

            function bezdiak(text) {
                tx = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1111111) + " ";
                txt = text;
                for (p = 0; p < txt.length; p++) {
                    if (sdiak.indexOf(txt.charAt(p)) != -1) {
                        tx += bdiak.charAt(sdiak.indexOf(txt.charAt(p)));
                    } else tx += txt.charAt(p);
                }
                tx = tx.replace(/ /g, "_");
                return tx;
            }
            nazev = "";

            function generuj_nazev(i) {
                neco = bezdiak(i);
                set_nazev(neco);
                return neco;
            }

            function set_nazev(i) {
                nazev = i;
            }

            function vypis_nazev() {
                return nazev;
            }

            function smazat(i) {
                if (confirm("Opravdu odstranit?")) {
                    var d = document.getElementById('url');
                    var olddiv = document.getElementById("radek" + i);
                    oFormObject = document.forms['form'];
                    d.removeChild(olddiv);
                    oFormObject = document.forms['form'];
                    pocet_obrazku = oFormObject.elements["pocet_obrazku"].value;
                    i = parseInt(pocet_obrazku);
                    oFormObject.elements["pocet_obrazku"].value = --i;
                }
            }

            function uprava_nahledu(nazev, id) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = "temp/neorezane_" + nazev;

                var width = img.width;
                var height = img.height;

                windowWidth = width + 100;
                windowHeight = height + 100;
                var centerWidth = (window.screen.width - windowWidth) / 2;
                var centerHeight = (window.screen.height - windowHeight) / 2;

                window.open("uploadcropper/uprava_nahledu.php?nazev=" + nazev + "&width=" + width + "&    height=" + height + "&id=" + id, "blank", "scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=" + windowWidth + "px,height=" + windowHeight + "px,left=" + centerWidth + "px,top=" + centerWidth + "px");

            }

            function zmenObrazek(nazev, id) {
                document.getElementById('neco' + id).innerHTML = "";
                var img = $("<img />").attr('src', 'temp/smaller_' + nazev)
                    .load(function() {

                    $("#neco" + id).append(img);

                });
            }
            id_obrazku = 0;
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                $('#file_upload').uploadify({
                    'uploader': 'uploadcropper/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
                        'script': 'uploadcropper/uploadify/uploadify.php',
                        'cancelImg': 'uploadcropper/uploadify/cancel.png',
                        'folder': 'temp',
                        'multi': true,
                        'buttonText': 'Vybrat fotografie',
                        'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.JPG;*.JPEG;',
                        'fileDesc': 'Fotografie, Obrázky, pouze JPG, JPEG',
                        'auto': true,
                        'method': 'POST',
                        'onSelect': function(event, ID, fileObj) {
                        $('#file_upload').uploadifySettings("scriptData", {
                            "nazev": generuj_nazev(fileObj.name)
                        });
                    },
                        'onComplete': function(event, ID, fileObj, response, data) {
                        nazev_obrazku = vypis_nazev();
                        //Validace extension
                        var fileName = fileObj.name;
                        var fileNameExt = fileName.substr(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                        //var validExtensions = new Array('jpg','jpeg');
                        if (fileNameExt == "jpg" || fileNameExt == "jpeg" || fileNameExt == "JPEG" || fileNameExt == "JPG") {
                            oFormObject = document.forms['form'];
                            pocet_obrazku = oFormObject.elements["pocet_obrazku"].value;

                            i = id_obrazku;
                            ++id_obrazku;
                            oFormObject.elements["pocet_obrazku"].value = ++pocet_obrazku;
                            fce = "uprava_nahledu('" + nazev_obrazku + "','" + i + "')";
                            var html = '';

                            html = '<div id="radek' + i + '" class="radek"><span class="tabulka_smazat"><img src="uploadcropper/delete.gif" alt="smazat" border="0" onclick="smazat(' + i + ');"></span><span class="ramecek"><div id="neco' + i + '"><img src="uploadcropper/edit.gif" alt="Upravit náhled" border="0" onclick="' + fce + '" class="button_edit"><img src="temp/small_' + nazev_obrazku + '" class="imgsmall" id="nahled' + i + '" title="Náhled obrázku" ></div></span><span class="hidden"><img src="temp/neorezane_' + nazev_obrazku + '" id="' + nazev_obrazku + '">Popis:<input name="popis' + i + '" id="popis' + i + '" type="text"></span><input id="file' + i + '" name="file' + i + '" type="text" value="' + nazev_obrazku + '">' + nazev_obrazku + ', cislo: ' + i + '</div>'
                            document.getElementById('url').innerHTML += html;
                        } else {
                            window.alert("Nesprávný typ souboru!");
                        }

                    }
                });


            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="POST" action="?obsah=ulozit&naz=reference&id=" id="form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Nahrávání a úprava obrázků</legend>
                <div class="admin_obrazky" class="admin_obrazky"> <span class="">Po vybrání obrázku se nahraje a zobrazí se automaticky ořezaný náhled, pokud vám ořez nevyhovuje, kliknutím na <img src="uploadcropper/edit.gif" class="ikona_text"> jej můžete ořezat. Ořez můžete provést jen jednou.</span>

                    <input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
                    <input id="pocet_obrazku" name="pocet_obrazku" type="text" value="0" />
                    <div id="url"></div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Vložit novou referenci" onclick="return checkform();">
            </p>
            <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
                //<!--
                function checkform() {
                    oFormObject = document.forms['form'];
                    if (oFormObject.elements["nadpis"].value == "") {
                        window.alert("Vyplňte prosím nadpis.");
                        return false;
                    } else {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                //-->
            </script>
        </form>
    </body>    
</html>
```

uploadify.php:

```
<?php
    include("resize.php");

    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['folder'] . '/';

    $nazev_souboru = $_POST["nazev"];

    $targetFile_neorezane =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) ."neorezane_".$nazev_souboru;
    $targetFile_small =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . "small_" . $nazev_souboru;
    $targetFile =  str_replace('//','/',$targetPath) . $nazev_souboru;



     $fileTypes  = str_replace('*.','',$_REQUEST['fileext']);
     $fileTypes  = str_replace(';','|',$fileTypes);
     $typesArray = split('\|',$fileTypes);
     $fileParts  = pathinfo($_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

     if (in_array($fileParts['extension'],$typesArray)) {
        // ulozit do tempu a zmensit pro nahled
    Resizer_thumb($tempFile,$targetFile_small,166,124);
    // zjisti, zda je obrazek na vysku nebo na sirku
    list($OrigWidth, $OrigHeight) = getimagesize($tempFile);
    if($OrigWidth/$OrigHeight<=1.338){
    // na vysku
    Resizer($tempFile,$targetFile_neorezane,166,0);
    }
    else{
    // na sirku
    Resizer($tempFile,$targetFile_neorezane,0,124);
    }

    Resizer($tempFile,$targetFile,640,640);

     } else {
        echo 'Nevhodný typ souboru.';
     }

    chmod($targetFile, 0666);

    } 
?>
```

Comment: I guess the script data variable is loaded before each upload happens, so you needn't update the scripdata value before each upload begins. The following should work:

    'scriptData'  : {"nazev": generuj_nazev(fileObj.name)}

Comment: But I don´t know the name of file.. can I find it earlier? scriptData is setted on page load and i fileObj isn´t exists...

Comment: @JaroslavŠtreit paste your solution as an answer and accept it - it might help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! I generate random string in onSelect and send by scriptData. Then all files (I assume they have different file names) have this code before filename. If somebody want code, send me a message.

Comment: I suggest providing the code here to help others in the future.